# Timber Twig - show elements if date/time is in the present/future

Tags: twig, timber

**Two part question:**

**One:**
I've used ACf to make some fields for linking to a Zoom meeting, including a date field and a time field, and I want a banner to only show if the date value is equal to or greater than the current date (i.e. today or future) - I've tried:

```
{% if post.meta('zoom_meeting_date') >= 'now'|date %}
    <!-- markup here -->
{% endif %}
```

This is only working if the date is in the future, not if it is today.

**Two:** I want a 'join' button that will only show once it is within say 15mins of the start time - no idea where to start with that one!

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you check whether your zoom date is actually set: If the value passed to the date filter is null or not set then the filter will use the current date: 
`{{ post.meta('zoom_meeting_date') is empty ? '' : mydate|date('m/d/Y') }}`

Comment: If I just print {{ post.meta('zoom_meeting_date') }} it correctly show tomorrow's date, so I know it isn't empty - I suspect it's something to do with ACFs date-picker field: without any filters on {{ post.meta('zoom_meeting_date') }} it prints out: 'Tuesday, 31 March 2020' - the formatting of the date is done in the ACF field UI, not in twig - presumably this messes with the comparison?

Comment: Could be, I am not familiar with that component. Or some timezone offset.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the same `date` filter without time on both sides of the comparison: `|date('m/d/Y')`

```php
{% if date("2020-03-30 23:59:59.000000")|date('m/d/Y')  >= 'now'|date('m/d/Y') %}
    <h1>bang<h1>
{% endif %}
{% if date("2020-03-30 00:00:01.000000")|date('m/d/Y')  >= 'now'|date('m/d/Y') %}
    <h1>boom<h1>
{% endif %}

{{ 'now'|date }}
{{ 'now'|date('m/d/Y') }}
```